# Loop through sheets and lock specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me loop through the sheets and only lock the specified range? I've tried something like this but it doesn't work properly:

```
Sub LoopThru()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To N
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Select
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Locked = False
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).FormulaHidden = False
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Range("A1:X1").Locked = True
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Protect Password:="abcd1"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to loop through the list of sheets in my document and unlock all cells and then only lock a specified range (with password).

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work properly"? Did you know that you have to lock the worksheet after you lock the individual cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here.

Loop through sheets listed in column A, unlock all cells on each sheet and then lock specific range and lock the sheet with a password xxx.

```
Sub PS()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To N
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Select
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Cells.Locked = False
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Range("A1:X1").Locked = True
            Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Protect Password:="xxx"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

To unlock loop through with:

```
Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Unprotect "xxx"
```

Comment: ++ nicely done. You can get rid of the line `Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Select` AND replace it with a line `If Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).ProtectContents = True Then Sheets(.Cells(i, "A").Value).Unprotect Password:="xxx"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopThru()
 For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
    c.Locked = True
 Next
End Sub
```

You'll then need to protect the sheet.  I type in protect sheet into my search bar on the top of excel and it brings up the protect window.

Did that do what you wanted?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Cells-and-Ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells

Comment: no need to loop. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells.Locked = True`